# list of keras callbacks generates error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_model'

Tags: python, keras, iterable-unpacking

I am writing a keras model where I want to use a few built-in keras callbacks, however I am probably making a grammar mistake somewhere that I cannot spot. The piece of code giving me troubles is the following:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
...
...
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.01, verbose=1, patience=5)
tb = TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir, write_graph=True, write_images=True, histogram_freq=0)
mc = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=n_epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_split=0.3,
                    callbacks=[es, tb, mc])
```

however in doing so I get the error `'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_model'`. Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063339/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-set-model) other question it seems that the problem is generated by the fact that `es, tb` are already tuples per sé and therefore positioning them into a list (in the call `callbacks=[es, tb, mc]`) raises the error. In fact

```
print(type(es))
print(type(tb))
print(type(mc))

<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint'>
```

This said, I do not understand how to work around it. `EarlyStopping` and `TensorBoard` return tuples, how are they supposed to be called in the keras callbacks list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpack your tuples - in this case, it's simple: `(object,)[0] == object` - but in general, you may have `(object1, object2)`, etc, which you can handle via `callbacks=[*es, *tb, *mc]`.

The `*` *unpacks iterables* - as a demo:

```
def print_unpacked(*positional_args):
    print(positional_args)
    print(*positional_args)
a = 1
b = ('dog',5)
```

```
print_unpacked(a,b)
# >> (1, ('dog',5))
# >> 1 ('dog',5)
print(a,b)
# >> 1 ('dog',5)
print(a,*b)
# >> 1 'dog' 5
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion: I have in fact made it work by taking the 0th element of the tuple, which in principle I don't even know what it corresponds to. I find strange that this isn't documented anywhere (or did I miss it?) as all the more or less official resources just present code as I have and claim that everything works eventually.

Comment: @gented Careful with 0-indexing, the tuple may pack more than one object. To be sure, run `print(es)`, `print(tb)`, etc and _verify_ that each tuple only holds one object - then it's fine. To unpack all, use `*`. -- Glad the problem's solved

Comment: Yes, of course the 0th index was just a trick that I used to verify that the problem was indeed in the list object and that unpacking must have been the solution.

Comment: @gented If the problem's solved and my suggestion was of help, consider greening a checkmarker

Answer (score 1):

You should remove comma at the end of following lines in your code posted above

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.01, verbose=1, patience=5),
tb = TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir, write_graph=True, write_images=True, histogram_freq=0),
```

Comment: Ooops that was a mis-copy/paste, the commas play no role. I have edited the question to correct it.